# How to multiply 2 input lists in python

Tags: python-3.x

Please help me understand how to code the following task in Python using input

Programming challenge description: 
Write a short Python program that takes two arrays a and b of length n
storing int values, and returns the dot product of a and b. That is, it returns
an array c of length n such that c[i] = a[i] · b[i], for i = 0,...,n−1.

Test Input: 
List1's input ==> 1 2 3 
List2's input ==> 2 3 4

Expected Output: 2 6 12

Answer (score 4):

Note that the dot product is defined in mathematics to be the sum of the elements of the vector `c` you want to build.

That said, here is a possibiliy using [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
c = [x * y for x, y in zip(a, b)]
```

And the mathematical dot product would be:

```
sum(x * y for x, y in zip(a, b))
```

---

If the lists are read from the keyboard, they will be read as string, you have to convert them before applying the code above.

For instance:

```
a = [int(s) for s in input().split(",")]
b = [int(s) for s in input().split(",")]
c = [x * y for x, y in zip(a, b)]
```

Comment: Hi Jean..Thank you very much for the suggestion, but i get this error ==> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
Because Im passing the lists a,b as inputs

Comment: @Sana That's another problem (you have to convert the input if you read strings), I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using `for` loops and appending

```
list_c = []
for a, b in zip(list_a, list_b):
    list_c.append(a*b)
```

And now the same, but in the more compact list comprehension syntax

```
list_c = [a*b for a, b in zip(list_a, list_b)]
```

From iPython

```
>>> list_a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> list_b = [2, 3, 4]
>>> list_c = [a*b for a, b in zip(list_a, list_b)]
>>> list_c
[2, 6, 12]
```

The `zip` function packs the lists together, element-by-element:

```
>>> list(zip(list_a, list_b))
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
```

And we use tuple unpacking to access the elements of each tuple.

Answer (score 0):

I came out with two solutions. Both or them are the ones that are expected in a Python introductory course:

```
#OPTION 1: We use the concatenation operator between lists.
def dot_product_noappend(list_a, list_b):
    list_c = []
    for i in range(len(list_a)):
        list_c = list_c + [list_a[i]*list_b[i]]
    return list_c


print(dot_product_noappend([1,2,3],[4,5,6])) #FUNCTION CALL TO SEE RESULT ON SCREEN



#OPTION 2: we use the append method
def dot_product_append(list_a, list_b):
    list_c = []
    for i in range(len(list_a)):
        list_c.append(list_a[i]*list_b[i])
    return list_c


print(dot_product_append([1,2,3],[4,5,6])) #FUNCTION CALL TO SEE RESULT ON SCREEN
```

Just note that the first method requires that you cast the product of integers to be a list before you can concatenate it to list_c. You do that by using braces (`[[list_a[i]*list_b[i]]` instead of `list_a[i]*list_b[i]`). Also note that braces are not necessary in the last method, because the append method does not require to pass a list as parameter.

I have added the two function calls with the values you provided, for you to see that it returns the correct result. Choose whatever function you like the most.

Answer (score 0):

From fetching the input and using map & lambda functions to provide the result.  If you may want to print the result with spaces between (not as list), use the last line

```
list1, list2 = [], []
list1 = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))
list2 = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))
result_list = list(map(lambda x,y : x*y, list1, list2))
print(*result_list)
```